# @@DATEFIRST not returning results as described in the docs

Tags: sql-server, date, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I have read this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

So I tried this experiment

```
declare @t table (test date)
insert into @t values ('20220404'), ('20220405'),('20220406'),('20220407'),('20220408'),('20220409'),('20220410')

select datename(weekday, test),
       datepart(weekday, test)
from   @t
```

it returns this

| COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 |
| --- | --- |
| Monday | 2 |
| Tuesday | 3 |
| Wednesday | 4 |
| Thursday | 5 |
| Friday | 6 |
| Saturday | 7 |
| Sunday | 1 |

I checked my value or @@DATEFIRST

```
select @@DATEFIRST
```

it returns `7`

So why do I not get this result then as described in the docs?

| COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 |
| --- | --- |
| Monday | 1 |
| Tuesday | 2 |
| Wednesday | 3 |
| Thursday | 4 |
| Friday | 5 |
| Saturday | 6 |
| Sunday | 7 |

**EDIT**

this is what I see in the docs

[image]

Comment: I don't see that result in the docs. The docs show what the _meaning_ of various values of `DATEFIRST` is. You have it at 7, so `DATEPART` considers (as the table in the docs illustrates) Sunday to be the first day of the week. So your Sunday gets a `weekday` of 1

Comment: This result expects `SET DATEFIRST 1`.

Comment: @AakashM I disagree, I clearly see in the docs a table with my expected results, and it clearly states in the last line that the value for @@datefirst is 7 which is the default

Comment: @Zhorov See my comment above

Comment: Just to confirm, when you look at the docs you see a page with one table, preceded by the text "Is an integer that indicates the first day of the week. It can be one of the following values." ? It is talking about **what the setting of `DATEFIRST` means**. It is *not* talking about 'what `DATEPART(weekday` returns for various days or settings'

Comment: @AakashM I added a screenshot from the docs in my question

Comment: note the header of the second column "first day of the week is". So if you select 7, the first day of the week is Sunday. If you select 1, you will get monday

Comment: I seem to read the documentation different than you guys, hence my confusion. English is not my mother tongue, but I find this documentation confusing some how

Comment: Perhaps the documentation of [DATEPART](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) helps. It shows a different table. It is confusing; you set Sunday (Day 7) as Day 1

Comment: @HoneyBadger Yes that helps understand it better, thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you may be misunderstanding the docs. The [docs for `DATEFIRST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) say, as you've seen:

> **Sets the first day of the week**

So, the value of `DATEFIRST` determines which *day* gets numbered *1*, the *first* day of the week. With `DATEFIRST` set to 7, as the table goes on to show, *Sunday* will be considered the *first* day of the week - day number 1.

With that setting, [`DATEPART` for `weekday`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) will return `1` for any Sunday, because Sunday is considered the *first* day of the week.

---

It is perhaps unfortunate that *numbers* are used as the argument to `SET DATEFIRST`, since naturally this confusion arises. It might have been nice if we could say `SET DATEFIRST Sunday` to make it obvious what we mean, but unfortunately that's not the syntax.

Comment: OK I understand my mistake now, I should not read this in the morning when not compete awake yet :)

Comment: Numbers are, in my opinion, the logical choice. Other options, like the name of the day, would be language specific, and so would not be able to be coded against easily. If `@@DATEFIRST = N'Monday'` won't work if your language is set to `FRENCH`.

Comment: @Larnu Yes, I totally agree, that is why I wanted to use numbers, but then I got into the @@datefirst setting where the documentation confused me.

Comment: `@@DATEFIRST` isn't a setting though, @Guido, it's a session based (environmental) variable.

Comment: @Larnu hm, from the docs `To see the current setting of SET DATEFIRST, use the @@DATEFIRST function.`

Comment: @Larnu So the confusion continues :)

Comment: I wouldn't call it a "function" personally, but that doesn't make it a setting. `@@DATEFIRST` *returns* a setting's value, but it isn't a setting itself. The setting is `DATEFIRST` (no leading @ characters).

Comment: @GuidoG  if you sent SET DATE FIRST 1;   you can get the results as documentation, look like the default value is 7